# "Illegal Access" on $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition

Tags: android, cordova, geolocation, ngcordova

Using the `cordova-plugin-geolocation` I'm getting this error on Android:

```
PositionError {code: 1, message: "Illegal Access"}
```

I checked the `plugins/android.json` file and the permissions are present

```
{
  "xml": "<uses-permission android:name=\"android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION\" />",
  "count": 1
},
{
  "xml": "<uses-permission android:name=\"android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION\" />",
  "count": 1
 }
```

Comment: Are you testing this on Android 6.0?

Comment: Tested on both 5 and 6, on real device and emulator.

Comment: If this issue on Android 6.0 then it must because of the dynamic permissions framework that was introduced in Android M. Don't know how `cordova` handles it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somehow it got fixed just by doing

```
cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-geolocation
```

and

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation
```

Answer (score 1):

Removing and reinstalling the geolocation plugin didn't solve the problem in my case. I had to remove and reinstall the entire android platform from cordova.

```
cordova platform rm android
cordova platform add android
```

Answer (score 0):

I was working with an Ionic 2 project and I got the same error.

I fixed it by manually adding the code below to **plugins/android.json** file:

```
{
    "xml": "<feature name=\"Geolocation\"><param name=\"android-package\" value=\"org.apache.cordova.geolocation.Geolocation\" /></feature>",
    "count": 1
}
```

Maybe this will help someone.